# javascript - Show/Hide text

Tags: javascript, visibility

I'm not good with programming, so I really would like some help.

I need a code that shows and hides a text when you click on a certain sentence. I have searched a lot over the Internet but I can't find something that works. Here is one of the codes that I have found. I would be happy if someone could help me and give me a working code!

Comment: Hi Emelie.  This site is intended to help those who have already put in a good faith effort to solve a problem, but have come up a bit short for whatever reason.  Can you post the code that you have written and which is not working?  You mention that you would post it but I don't see it there.  When you paste it in you can indent it by 4 spaces so that it formats correctly.

Comment: What mark-up are you working with? What elements are the various sentences wrapped in, what `id` or `class` names do they have? Please, if you can, post code that shows what you've got.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's Toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Because you're new to programming, you might want to watch these video series about jQuery: http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/

Alternative solution without jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> <== click Here
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
```

You can also have a look at the related questions on the right of this page :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JavaScript framework:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Text 1</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
<p>Text 3</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

But if you hide the text, you can't click on to redisplay it. So you need to find a clickable visual aid to redisplay the text. I let you think about it. `:)`

Comment: JQuery isn't an answer. The question made no mention of using it; it strictly asked for Javascript.

Comment: When I started the javascript I would have been the happiest of men if I had learned about the existence of jQuery.

Comment: That's wonderful. Post that as a suggestion **after** you've written to an answer to the question asked (meaning a Javascript answer), or as a comment to the original question. It's not an answer to this one, any more than posting a C# answer to an Objective C question would be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure that this would work, but you could try putting a blank picture over the text you want to hide and when you want to view the text, just remove the blank square. I'm not exactly 100% sure it would work though. I'm not as good at javascript as I am with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed the world's best example on this website:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

The tutorial shows using pure HTML with JavaScript to do the job!